# How to hide dynamic content if it's width is greater than screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I have two elements displayed inline-block; one an image and one text. The text is dynamic so it can have any width. I want to hide the image when these two elements combined become wider than the page.

I've tried this on page resize:

```
if ($(window).width() == $('#id').width()) {
    document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'block';
}
```

This isn't working correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: `if ($(window).width() < $('#header-top-inner').offsetWidth())` - offsetWidth accounts for padding and borders, you could switch back to `.width()` if need be.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the image and text in the block but cut part of them which they are out of the screen because of larger width , you can add 'overflow:hidden 'to your inline block. Try it.

Comment: please add more codes about your element here and let me get familiar with your structure

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to `<=` in case the initial window is less than or equal:

```
function updateLayout() {
    //Hide header image on smaller screens
    if ($(window).width() <= $('#logo-image').width()) {
        document.getElementById('logo-image').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('logo-image').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
}
```

[updated](http://jsfiddle.net/rs2aef7w/2/)

Comment: You could just do `$('#logo-image').width()` instead of `$('#header-top-inner').width()`